# How do you make a button that adds a number

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain some way for me to change this to actually add the numbers? I am new to coding and also using notepad so its not giving me errors in the syntax.

My JavaScript:

```
function street() {
    var x=Math.floor(Math.random()*2 + 1);
    var z=document.getElementById("test")
    if (x == 1) {
        alert('This should add 1');
        z.innerhtml = z + 1
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
        alert('This should add 2');
        z.innerhtml = z + 1;
    }
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<p>Adding</p>`
<p id="test">0</p>
<button type = "button" onclick "street()">Add</p>
```

Comment: Put the script after your HTML, or use an `onload` function, it's also `innerHTML`, and you'll have to wrap that in `parseInt()` to convert that to a number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Um, *please* go read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for how to format code (and other things) in your question (and also answer).

Comment: And define `onclick=` correctly, and don't use an Element as a number.

Comment: Also, notice you're trying to close your button with a `</p>` tag. Change that to `</button>`.

Answer (score 2):

`z.innerHTML = parseInt(z.innerHTML) + 1; // or 2`. And you missed the `=` after your onclick (along with many other syntactical oversights already pointed out).

Comment: Let me add some value to the answer so OP knows exactly what is going on. Even if the inner html of your variable `z` is a number, it's considered a string, text etc. You may ask "Well why doesn't it just auto parse it into a number, why can't it be smart?" Because `"1"+"10"` is a string concatenation which just gives you back a new string `110` in this case. In other words the `+` operator does different things based on the data type.

Answer (score 1):

My own take would be:

```
function street() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*2 + 1),
        z = document.getElementById("test"),
        // parses the text of the element, turning it into a base-10 number:
        n = parseInt(z['textContent' || 'innerText'], 10);

    // sets the text of the element to be the sum of
    // the current number + generated number:
    z['textContent' || 'innerText'] = n + x;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6pNSH/).

The reason to use `parseInt()` is because the `+` operator will either add two numbers together or concatenate two strings. If you mix strings and numbers the type of the number is coerced to be a string, and `'1' + 2` > `'12'`.

Therefore:

```
1 + 2 // 3
'1' + '2' // '12'
'1' + 2 // '12'
1 + '2' // '12'
```

My use of `['textContent' || 'innerText']` (W3C approach or MS approach) is to avoid accidentally picking up any serialised HTML elements that might have been appended to the `'test'` element.

Incidentally, this line:

```
var z=document.getElementById("test")
```

finds a DOM node, not a string; to *find* the string contained within the DOM node you need to use either `textContent`, `innerText` or `innerHTML` (the latter is the simplest, and most cross-browser compatible, but will fail if the numbers are wrapped in any child elements).

I'd also suggest moving away from obtrusive JavaScript, and binding the event-handler outside of your HTML (this makes future modification easier, since there's less hunting down of `onclick` event-handlers to modify function-calls); in the first instance this involves giving the `button` an `id` by which to select it:

```
// getting a reference to the DOM node:
var button = document.getElementById('button');

// binding the function to the event of the button being clicked:
button.onclick = street;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6pNSH/1/).

Alternatively:

```
// get all the button elements:
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
    // select the first of those elements:
    button = buttons[0];

button.onclick = street;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6pNSH/2/).

Preferable (under contemporary browsers that implement DOM level 2 and/or 3):

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
    button = buttons[0];

button.addEventListener('click', street);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6pNSH/3/).

Answer (score 1):

I remember when I was new to coding as well. There are a number of issues here.

First of all, your html has to exist before the JavaScript can use it. The browser will load page elements from top to bottom so, without any clever tricks, your JavaScript needs to be below your html.

Second, the onclick attribute is sort of a no-no in the JavaScript world because the way it works is really inefficient. You can actually handle it better through actually JavaScript.

Then there's the matter of the actual code mistakes. Here's how it should look:

```
<p>Adding</p>
<p id="test">0</p>
<button id="mybutton" type="button">Add</button>
```

Then it's best to put your JavaScript into its own file, but if you have it on the page you'd do this:

```
<script>
function street() {
    var x=Math.floor(Math.random()*2 + 1);
    var z=document.getElementById("test");
    if (x === 1) {
        alert('This should add 1');
        z.innerHTML = parseInt(z.innerHTML) + 1;
    }
    else if (x === 2) {
        alert('This should add 2');
        z.innerHTML = parseInt(z.innerHTML) + 2;
    }
}

document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = street;
</script>
```

EDIT:

As far as adding the numbers is concerned, when you pull out some innerHTML, it is always in the form of text. When you try to add text to text or a number to text, you always get text. So, for example, "4" + 2 equals "42" and "4" + "2" also equals "42". The purpose of the parseInt function is that it turns your text into an ACTUAL number that can be added to other numbers. When you drop your new number back in to the innerHTML, it is converted back to text again.

Comment: To be more clear, `parseInt` will turn your text into a number. You need that to do real math. Also, JavaScript is case sensitive so `innerhtml` won't work. It needs to be `innerHTML`. By assigning the `street` function to the button with JavaScript, the browser won't have to fire up the JavaScript compiler whenever you click the button. Just a little efficiency boost there.

Comment: All of the answers except for @JoshBjelovuk are missing the point that the OP doesn't understand the difference between a number as a string and a number as a float data type. Teach a man to fish, don't just give him one.

Comment: @LéMuffinMan: not to be unduly picky, but I think I definitely covered that point...

Comment: I think you answered as I was writing it, sorry. Unfortunately I can't go back and edit it.

Comment: No problem, I tend to do a lot of editing after posting the initial answer, with the hope of adding further value as I go. But I thought that was in my initial post (though I could, of course, be quite wrong; edits do tend to blur together).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function street() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1),
        el = document.getElementById('test'),
        val = parseInt(el.innerHTML, 10);
    el.innerHTML = val + x;
  }
</script>
<p>Adding</p> 
<p id="test">0</p> 
<button type="button" onclick="street()">Add</button>
```

this will increment the value each time you click the button